# Order by custom Woocommerce product sorting in a WP_Query for Bootstrap 4 Carousel

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to get Woocommerce products to display as per Custom ordering, as seen here: https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/managing-products/#section-23. This ordering works on my shop page but is not working in my WP_Query, which I am using to display the products in a Bootstrap 4 Carousel, instead they are being displayed in the date order.

```
<?php $loop = new WP_Query(array(
      'post_type' => 'product',
      'posts_per_page' => 8,
        'orderyby' => 'menu_order',
      'order' => 'ASC',
      'tax_query' => array(
                array(
                'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
                'field'    => 'slug',
                'terms'    => $category_slug
        ),
        )

    )); 
      ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try running `var_dump($loop->request);` to check what the orderby parameter is set to on the page. It could be that its being edited by something else, if it is being changed then try adding:

```
remove_all_filters('posts_orderby');
```

Before you run `new WP_Query`.